# Forward name server for faster load times

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, china

I have a website hosted in China, which must be hosted there for various reasons. I also cannot change hosting companies for various reasons. It is a website that is accessed worldwide, however it has atrocious ping rates from everywhere but China.

This is just an idea, so this may be impossible and/or not make any sense, but here it goes. A friend of mine has used proxies which helped his ping and load times from servers in Korea. Is there any way I can do this with my server? Perhaps a service which forwards my name servers to somewhere with much better global ping rates?

Any other ideas which will make pings/load times fester other than this are greatly appreciated as well. Please keep in mind when answering:

1. I cannot change servers
2. I do not have access to configure the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have no way to serve the content from china and get better times.

What you can do is:

- Crap your chinese DNS setup. There is no need for the NAME servers to be in china at all. Get DNS Servers registered from a DNS provider and just use those.
- If possible (makes no sense for some totally dynamic apps) use an external server )outside china) with a reverse proxy. Anything the proxy serves will be fast ,but whenever a request has to be answered from your server it wil be slower. The question now is how much can be cached (static files, images etc.).

Both requre you to have access to the domain so you can change the IP addresses for the DNS Servers and the IP Addresses serves for the website.

Comment: I found this: www.varnish-cache.org.

Is this what I need?

Comment: No idea. Never head of this.

Comment: Varnish is a pretty cool reverse proxy.  There is even a tag "varnish" on SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/varnish